# Why is my subdomain not showing up?

Tags: virtualhost, web-hosting, subdomain, cpanel

I am hosting a website on Host Gator: http://www.flowerwood.com. It is working correctly. I also have a subdomain that I setup using cPanel called http://plants.flowerwood.com

Right now I have a very basic html page on there that simply says, plants.flowerwood.com home. The only problem is the page does not show and it redirects to the search page of the main site.

I am not sure where to begin to know how to resolve this and could use some good advice. How do I resolve this kind of an issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://www.flowerwood.com is pointing to 69.85.232.203
- http://plants.flowerwood.com is pointing to 98.124.199.1

Change the DNS record for the plants dubdomain to point to the same IP as flowerwood.com.

(This post assumes default behavior of a cPanel/Apache setup. Also assuming that the subdomain is also on the same server. All pretty vanilla assumptions given shared hosting.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Someone else had redirected the URL to another directory. Too many cooks!

Answer (score 1):

Have up updated your DNS records to reflect the additional DNS host (plants.flowerwood.com)?

Comment: I'll take a look.